# SQLite one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have two classes on C# with "one to many" relationship.

```
public class LocalCompany : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private bool isActive;
    public bool IsActive { get { return isActive; } set { isActive = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsActive"); } }

    private string name;
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    private string address;
    public string Address { get { return address; } set { address = value; OnPropertyChanged("Address"); } }

    private string unp;
    public string UNP { get { return unp; } set { unp = value; OnPropertyChanged("UNP"); } }
    public ICollection<LocalUser> LocalUsers { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

public class LocalUser : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private bool isActive;
    public bool IsActive { get { return isActive; } set { isActive = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsActive"); } }

    private string email;
    public string Email { get { return email; } set { email = value; OnPropertyChanged("Email"); } }

    private string name;
    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    private string address;
    public string Address { get { return address; } set { address = value; OnPropertyChanged("Address"); } }

    private string passportNumber;
    public string PassportNumber { get { return passportNumber; } set { passportNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("PassportNumber"); } }

    private string passportIssue;
    public string PassportIssue { get { return passportIssue; } set { passportIssue = value; OnPropertyChanged("PassportIssue"); } }

    public ICollection<LocalCard> LocalCards { get; set; }

    public int? LocalCompanyId { get; set; }
    private LocalCompany localCompany;
    public LocalCompany LocalCompany { get { return localCompany; } set { localCompany = value; OnPropertyChanged("LocalCompany"); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
```

For interaction with database I use Entity Framework 6.

1. I'm creating LocalCompany item with "AAA" name and saving into DB. It is assigned a Id "1".
2. I'm creating LocalUser item with "Alex" name and I write company AAA in the LocalCompany property.

However, EF does not write 1 into LocalCompanyId property. EF creating second AAA company with "2" Id and writing 2 into LocalCompanyId.

If I write LocalCompanyId then I get same result.
Tell me please what is my mistake?
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: `If I write LocalCompanyId then I get same result` Can you explain that? If you create a new LocalUser with LocalCompanyId = 1, I do not believe EF creates a LocalCompany with Id = 2.

Comment: If I write 1 into LocalCompanyId and don't write anything into LocalCompany, EF creating second AAA company with "2" Id and writing 2 into LocalCompanyId like in a first case.

If I write 1 into LocalCompanyId and write company object into LocalCompany, EF creating second AAA company with "2" Id and writing 2 into LocalCompanyId too.

Comment: I found problem! It problem has because I write company object into LocalCompany property before.

Comment: I found problem! It problem has because I write company object into LocalCompany property before. Now I am writing LocalCompanyId, not writing anythyng into LocalCompany, foreign key is 1 and second company is not creating and all works fine!)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem! It problem has because I write company object into LocalCompany property before. Now I am writing LocalCompanyId, not writing anythyng into LocalCompany, foreign key is 1 and second company is not creating and all works fine!)))